# How to use variable in SQL from powershell script

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run a SQL from Power Shell(which is on my windows 7 64 bit desktop) and the remote database host is MS SQL Server 2012.

**The code is:**

```
$var1 = 'string';

function Get-ODBC-Data{
   param(
   [string]$query=$('
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM [master].[sys].[table_name]                
                                WHERE col2 = ''$var1''
                                ;
'),
   [string]$username='db_user_name',
   [string]$password='db_password'
   )
   $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
   $conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=123.456.78.90;Initial Catalog=master;Uid=$username;Pwd=$password;"
   $conn.open()
   $cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
   $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
   (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($ds) | out-null
   $conn.close()
   $ds.Tables[0]
}

 $result = Get-ODBC-Data

Write-Host "SQL_Output: " $result[0];
```

If I use 'string' in the SQL's where clause instead of $var1 then te script works fine and gives expected result.

**Quetion**
But I want to be able to pass any string as $var1 to the script as parameter. Then use it in the where clause of the SQL. How can I achieve this?

**What I tried**
I have tried to enclose $var1 in 1,2 or 3 single quotes in the where clause in attempt to escape the single quote. Also tried adding/removing single quote from 'string' when $var1 is assigned value. I did try [string]$var1 = 'string' as well but none of these worked and I keep getting error mostly related to SQL syntax.

Comment: Not sure if you can do that in a parameters default value. You will probably need a backtick to escape the single quotes. You can concat strings with + so... `$query ='Where col = \`'' + $var1 + '\`';` should work. why don't you create the query Inc value and then execute the statement.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using `$query ='Where col = `'' + $var1 + '`';` gives syntax error: `Unexpected token '`'' in expression or statement`. I am open to try different approach. Can you give me some idea about creating query in Inc and then executing the statement? I don't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Get-ODBC-Data{
   param(
   [string]$query=$("
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM [master].[sys].[table_name]                
                                WHERE col2 = '$($var1)'
                                ;
"),
   [string]$username='db_user_name',
   [string]$password='db_password'
   )
   $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
   $conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=123.456.78.90;Initial Catalog=master;Uid=$username;Pwd=$password;"
   $conn.open()
   $cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
   $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
   (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($ds) | out-null
   $conn.close()
   $ds.Tables[0]
}

 $result = Get-ODBC-Data

Write-Host "SQL_Output: " $result[0];
```

The following runs fine on my setup, and shows the correct results:

```
$var1 = "test22"

function Get-ODBC-Data{
   param(
   [string]$query=$("
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM [master].[sys].[table_name]                
                                WHERE col2 = '$($var1)'
                                ;
"),
   [string]$username='db_user_name',
   [string]$password='db_password'
   )

   return $query

}

$result = Get-ODBC-Data

Write-Host " ################### Query ######################## "
Write-Host $result
```

However, you may have a much easier time just passing the entire query into the function as a parameter rather than just one variable part of the query.

Or setting it inside the function and passing **$var1** as a mandatory parameter like so:

```
function Get-ODBC-Data{
   param(
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$var1,
   [string]$username='db_user_name',
   [string]$password='db_password'
   )
   $query="
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM [master].[sys].[table_name]                
                                WHERE col2 = '$($var1)'
                                ;"

   return $query

}

$result = Get-ODBC-Data -var1 "working"

Write-Host " ################### Query ######################## "
Write-Host $result
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using `WHERE col2 = '$($var1)'` gives syntax error: `Unexpected token '$(' in expression or statement`. I also tried to use `WHERE col2 = ''$($var1)''` which doesn't give syntax error but shows error: `Cannot index into null array` which I think indicates that SQL didn't fetch any data.

Comment: Did you also use " instead of ' to wrap the query?

Comment: That's perfect! I had single quotes around the SQL instead of double quotes and that was reason for the syntax errors. `The following runs fine on my setup, and shows the correct results:` I am using that version and it is working as expected for me as well. Thank you so much for reverting back with the suggestion.

Comment: Not a problem, I would still suggest using the last piece of code as it gives you more control over what $var1 is. You won't have to set it every time just pass it to the function as a parameter.

Comment: I had to upgrade this script and now I am using second and third version of your answer. I have asked a new question about it at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50418878/3209087
I would greatly appreciate if you could take a look at this question when you have some time. I think it is related with probable need for looping.